# Unable to copy from VIM to clipboard using "+y command

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clipboard

I am unable to copy strings from vim paste them somewhere else, for example in the terminal, using "+y. I run Ubuntu on my laptop, the vim version is vim-gtk, it has xterm_clipboard and clipboard enable. What could be causing this?

I am able to copy and paste using "+y "+p in vim, but I can't seem to do it outside of it

Comment: This should work. What is the output of `set clipboard?`?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu; select and right click ( on the text area u want to copy) with your computer-mouse, then copy and now paste it anywhere you want to in your computer